# Can an OOTB SPFx Web part consume a custom SPFx Web part component exposed data?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts

Can an OOTB SPFx Web part consume a custom SPFx Web part component exposed data?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/dynamic-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, we cannot connect custom SPFx web parts with SharePoint OOTB web parts using dynamic data.

We can only connect two or more custom SPFx web parts using dynamic data.

As for OOTB web parts, we can only connect OOTB web parts with each other, documentation: [Connect web parts in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec)